# Android: SQLite find data

Tags: android

Need some help. I have a table with some columns..like "name" , "phone" etc...
How to chek, is there a name "Jone" or not ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write simple SQL statement and see if there are returned results or not...

Answer (score 0):

Check with the following code

//sampleDb is the database object you are referring

```
Cursor cur = sampleDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Constants.TABLE_NAME,
                null);

        if (cur= null) {

            if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                 String title = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("Title")); 
                 // "Title" is the field name(column) of the Table                 

                } while (cur.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

**Check whether the String title is returning any data or not.**

Comment: `if (cur= null)` what's this?